# Nginx 301 redirect with round brackets in URL

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm having difficulties getting a basic 301 redirect to work in nginx when the URL in question has round brackets.

Typically, I would simply use this type of basic location rule (without brackets):

```
location /abc/def {
rewrite /abc/def http://new.domain.com/abc/def/ permanent;
}
```

There are circumstances as mentioned above where the URL has round brackets:

source url: domain1.com/abc/def(ghi)
target url: domain2.com/abc/defghi

```
location /abc/def(ghi) {
rewrite /abc/def(ghi) http://new.domain2.com/abc/defghi permanent;
}
```

Unfortunately, it wasn't as simple as the first example. I've since altered the rule several times to include escaping, urlencoded for open and close round brackets, regex to allow single character capture at the brackets and nothing seems to work.

Escaping via:

```
location /abc/def\(ghi\)
```

How can I get a 301 redirect to work in nginx when the URL has parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

```
location /abc/def(ghi) {
    return 301 http://new.domain2.com/abc/defghi;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million for the amazingly fast response and resolution!

Answer (score 0):

though in this specific case VBart's answer works it's not a general fix.

the basic problem is that the `(` and `)` are special char in regexes,
the general fix for that is to escape those special chars
**BUT** the gotcha is that escaping with `\` only works if you enclose the regex in `"`

like so:

```
location /abc/def(ghi) {
  rewrite "/abc/def\(ghi\)" http://new.domain2.com/abc/defghi permanent;
}
```

Comment: _only works if you enclose the regex in `"`_ No, you're wrong here. It should be enclosed in quotes only if regex includes `{` or `;` charters. See docs: http://nginx.org/r/rewrite

Comment: The problem was that author put `\ ` before `(` and `)` in the prefix `location` (not regexp one). http://nginx.org/r/location